# jQuery UI autocomplete and $.getJSON problem

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, getjson

I would like to use getjson method after UI autocomplete.

```
("#kod").autocomplete("kod.php", {
        width: 135,
        matchContains: true,                                               
        selectFirst: true      
            });

$("#kod").live("change",function() {
                $.getJSON('ajax2.php', {option: $(this).val()}, function(data) {    
                      $("#miasto").val(data.inputValue);  


            });

          });
```

If I type something traditional way or I choose value from list with keyboard it works ok. But if    I choose something from autocomplete with mouse it doesn't work. Where is the problem? Thanks for help

Comment: i dont know Why people dont mention which `jquery plugin` they are using; there are several plugin for auto complete. how do we help without knowing exact plugin???

Comment: i think he is using the [UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [`autocompletechange`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-change) event.

```
$("#kod").live("autocompletechange",function() {
            $.getJSON('ajax2.php', {option: $(this).val()}, function(data) {    
                  $("#miasto").val(data.inputValue);

 });
```